# The Microsoft Suite is supported? or onedrive?

Tags: applications, software-installation, software-recommendation

I have mandatory needs with onedrive, so it is important that it is compatible, so the question is, if I can download office or even one drive as app and not only on the web?
I'm tired of windows and the only thing that prevents me from using linux is this question, so I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question should be more like, "Does Microsoft OneDrive support Linux?". The answer to that is no, Microsoft OneDrive does not officially provide Linux clients. You may access OneDrive from your internet browser to view and upload files.

Beyond that there are some open source projects you may have already seen from  a Google search to give you a similar experience to Windows version of OneDrive on Linux. This thread suggestions some options: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/onedrive-on-linux/m-p/1318644 mentions this project: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/

Answer (score 0):

There are some recent videos on YouTube that talk about OneDrive on Linux. https://youtu.be/4mA3_ZX3SIw
Just search Linux OneDrive. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called ExpanDrive, which maps to my google drives, my DropBox, and my OneDrives.